# What is 0000 in the text?

Tags: ascii

Here is a test file in /tmp.
debian@debian:~$ xxd /tmp/test
0000000: 0000 6920 616d 2068 6572 650a 7765 2061  ..i am here.we a
0000010: 7265 2068 6572 650a                      re here.
debian@debian:~$ nano /tmp/test
^@^@i am here
we are here

0000  is  ^@^@??  in ascii table ,94  is ^, 64 is @.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

^@ is just nano's way of displaying 0 binary, which is not a displayable ascii character.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know:

`0000000` is represented as numbering.

`0000 6920 616d 2068 6572 650a 7765 2061` is represented as "**i am here**"

`7265 2068 6572 650a` is represented as "**we are here**"